# How to query data from CnosDB using python?

Tags: python, cnosdb

I have some data stores in cnosdb v2.4.0.

```sql
select count(*) from sea;

+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 18000           |
+-----------------+
```

I wrote python script following the [documentation](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/v2.4/develop/query.html#query-data-1) to query data:

```py
import requests

username = "*"
password = "*"
cnosdb_url = "127.0.0.1"
cnosdb_port = "8902"
database_name = "public"
sql_statement = "select count(*) from sea"

url = f"http://{cnosdb_url}:{cnosdb_port}/api/v1/sql?db={database_name}&pretty=true"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
data = {"query": sql_statement}

response = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), headers=headers, json=data)

print(response.text)
```

Then it told me error messages:

```bash
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected an SQL statement, found: {"}
```

---

The following code works well, the document is wrong.

```py
import requests

username = "*"
password = "*"
cnosdb_url = "127.0.0.1"
cnosdb_port = "8902"
database_name = "public"
sql_statement = "select count(*) from sea"

url = f"http://{cnosdb_url}:{cnosdb_port}/api/v1/sql?db={database_name}&pretty=true"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
data = sql_statement

response = requests.post(url, auth=(username, password), headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: It seems that there is no question here and you solved it already? Either post the answer as an actual answer, and make the question strictly a question; or else delete this post if you don't want to ask a question.